# Oracle Client trace not generating

Tags: oracle, trace

I'm using Oracle Client 12.1.0.2 and I need to generate client trace because im unable to connect my sql developer to the database server. However, i'm unable to generate the trace.

Here is my sqlnet.ora:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = 16 
TRACE_FILE_CLIENT = client
TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT = 'D:\app\client\product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin'
TRACE_TIMESTAMP_CLIENT = ON
TRACE_UNIQUE_CLIENT = ON
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED=OFF
```

I have the rights to write in the folder but unable to generate the logs.

I tried the same with net manager also.

But no luck.

Comment: SQL Developer uses (by default) the JDBC **thin** driver which does not use the TNS config files at all. What exactly is the error message you get when you try to connect?

Comment: Network IO adapter error. Oracle Support is asking for trace files and so Im trying.

Answer (score 2):

Add following line to sqlnet.ora:

```
adr_base=off
```

You should be able to find your traces then.
Without it, all client traces go to %userprofile%\oracle\oradiag_%username% folder.

Comment: tried and ain't working.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you configure SQLDeveloper to use the installed Oracle Client and the OCI/Thick driver.

```
Tools / Preferences / Database / Advanced

Mark Use Oracle Client.
Browse the client home.
Mark Use OCI/Thick Driver.
```

Restart SQL Developer.

Since you have access to MOS, steps are shown here:

**How to Use and Trace Oracle Net with SQLDeveloper (Doc ID 1991711.1)**

Alternatively, you can use a different tracing method for SQLDeveloper:

**How to generate a SQLNET trace with SQL Developer (Doc ID 1390063.1)**